# Auto run of application dialogs

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

We have installed some applications on Pepper each of which have some dialog scripts associated with it. The issue is that every time Naoqi starts, these dialogs are seen as running in the Robot Applications window even though the behaviours associated with these dialogs is not running.

Is anyone else facing the same issue? Our Naoqi version is 2.5.10.7. We have contacted the customer support but did not receive any satisfactory response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These dialogues are probably flagged as being "collaborative dialogue". This means that when the robot is in Autonomous Life, *all* collaborative dialogues will be loaded simultaneously (which is good - that allows you to use conversation topics and vocal triggers from all applications on the robot).